# JSHint ignore `!function(){ /* ... */ }()` pattern

Tags: javascript, jshint

How can I configure JS Hint to ignore JSHint ignore `!function(){ /* ... */ }()` pattern. Currently, it is throwing warnings for me to tell me it expects a statement or assignment. I expect this is due to `!function` converting the function into a function expression, which goes nowhere. I know I could do... `var garbage = !function ...` but I don't want to change the source code to please JS Hint, I want to tell JS Hint that it is ok to use an operator to coerce a function into an expression.

Comment: `/*jshint expr:true */`

Comment: thanks @elclanrs that works - however, I would prefer a solution that does not require the source to be modified - do you know of a way?

Comment: ok @elclanrs I put it in my config file, and it works - thanks. I am concerned about the side effects - what other kinds of expression warnings would be supressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it. Put this at the beginning of the file or add the `expr` option to your `.jshintrc` configuration.

```
/*jshint expr:true */
```

This option allows any raw expression such as:

```
!function(){}();
a || b();
a ? b() : c();
```

You'd write it like this to avoid the warning:

```
(function(){}());
if (!a) b();
if (a) {
  b();
} else {
  c();
}
```

Comment: I would also put a semicolon before the self executing function, to prevent it getting mixed with previous statement, especially if js files are concatenated with arbitrary libraries in build scripts etc...